# jdbc mysql executeUpdate not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
PreparedStatement  stmt1 = con.prepareCall("update khol SET emailcnf =  'ya' where khol.id = 
     (SELECT guiid.id FROM guiid WHERE guiid.gchbi = 'htg1' and guiid.typ = 'reg')");

System.out.println("rows COUNT "+stmt1.executeUpdate());

stmt1.close();
```

Output Is:

> rows COUNT 0

0 Is Returned By executeUpdate And When I  Run Same Statement Directly In Mysql it works fine.

Comment: Use `con.prepareStatement` instead of `con.prepareCall`.

Comment: It Is Not Working , I Had Already tried with con.prepareStatement

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the same database?

Comment: Yes And Other Single Statement Like insert,delete,update Are Working Fine  but when i try to run update with select statement in jdbc but it does't work

Comment: Aborted connection 6 to db: 'atg' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 7 to db: 'atg' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 8 to db: 'atg' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 10 to db: 'atg' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
This Is My Last Line From My MYSQL LOGS

Answer (score 0):

You should use `con.prepareStatement()` instead of `con.prepareCall()`

Check out the following link to help you understand the difference between `createStatement()` `prepareSatement()` and `prepareCall()`

http://javaconceptoftheday.com/statement-vs-preparedstatement-vs-callablestatement-in-java/

The following should work:

```
PreparedStatement  stmt1 = con.prepareStatement("update khol SET emailcnf =  'ya' where khol.id = 
            (SELECT guiid.id FROM guiid WHERE guiid.gchbi = 'htg1' and guiid.typ = 'reg')");

System.out.println("rows COUNT "+stmt1.executeUpdate());

stmt1.close();
```

Comment: It Is Not Working , I Had Already tried with con.prepareStatement

Comment: In your specific example, you could actually use `createStatement()` but as soon as you start to add dynamic parameters you will want to make sure you use prepared statements to avoid an SQL injection vulnerability being introduced.

Comment: Show your `con` assignment.

Comment: I Am Using stored procedure but here i had just pasted replica statement  and i tried as much in possible way to run update with select statement in jdbc but it does't work

Comment: if (con == null) {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atg", "root", "root");
                }

Comment: Connection con;

Comment: Aborted connection 6 to db: 'atg' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) Aborted connection 7 to db: 'atg' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) Aborted connection 8 to db: 'atg' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) Aborted connection 10 to db: 'atg' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) This Is My Last Line From My MYSQL LOGS

Comment: Try setting `max_allowed_packet` to a much larger value. The default is 1M.

You can set `max_allowed_packet` to 256M in /etc/my.cnf or my.ini

Comment: Still Same Problem After Changing max_allowed_packet And I Had Restarted Mysql Service after Doing Change But Same Error Still